# How do I avoid obfuscating logic in a `loop`?

Tags: rust

Trying to respect Rust safety rules leads me to write code that is, in this case, less clear than the alternative.

It's marginal, but must be a very common pattern, so I wonder if there's any better way.

The following example *doesn't compile*:

```rust
async fn query_all_items() -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut items = vec![];
    let limit = 10;

    loop {
        let response = getResponse().await;

        // response is moved here
        items.extend(response);

        // can't do this, response is moved above
        if response.len() < limit {
            break;
        }
    }

    items
}
```

In order to satisfy Rust safety rules, we can pre-compute the break condition:

```rust
async fn query_all_items() -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut items = vec![];
    let limit = 10;

    loop {
        let response = getResponse().await;

        let should_break = response.len() < limit;

        // response is moved here
        items.extend(response);

        // meh
        if should_break {
            break;
        }
    }

    items
}
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Perhaps there's a more functional solution. If this were synchronous code you could [create an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html) and use [`take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) to stop when the limit is exceeded. My async is rusty so I'm not sure what the async equivalent would be.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I love the idea! Exploring this right now

Comment: Another variant: `let response_len = response.len()`, and then use `response_len` instead. I don't think you'll find a perfect answer.

Comment: I was playing around `take_while` as @JohnKugelman suggested but I'm finding it difficult to mix with the `futures` here. For some reason, my question was edited so it uses bytes, but in my use case, I am dealing with async requests.
@user4815162342: I'll be doing that for the foreseeable future, and maybe swapping the branches to move the exit at the end of the loop: I find it more readable not to break in the middle of it: `while () { /* play with data */ if response_len == limit { /* prepare next query */ } else { break; } }`

Comment: The async analogue of iterators is [streams](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/stream/index.html), but they're still experimental. See [`stream::take_while`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.take_while).

Comment: @JohnKugelman great idea. In the meantime, I'd suggest taking a look at [`tokio-stream`](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/streams)

Comment: Side note: this code looks fishy to me. Are you sure you want to stop once you get a single `response` that _by itself_ is larger than the limit? As opposed to stopping once you have accumulated at least `limit` values in `items`?

Comment: @Jmb: `limit` refers to the pagination limit, in order to query all pages, we need to request every page until we find one that is incomplete. Makes sense?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Daniel's point that this should be a `while` rather than a `loop`, though I'd move the logic to the `while` rather than creating a boolean:

```
let mut len = limit;
while len >= limit {
    let response = queryItems(limit).await?;

    len = response.len();

    items.extend(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In all fairness, you'd still have the `items` variable outside, so both `let mut items` and `let mut items_len`, introducing a bit of duplication outside the while loop...

Answer (score 1):

Not that you should do this, but an async stream version is possible. However a plain old loop is much easier to read.

```rust
use futures::{future, stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.19
use rand::{
    distributions::{Distribution, Uniform},
    rngs::ThreadRng,
};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use tokio; // 1.15.0

async fn get_response(rng: Arc<Mutex<ThreadRng>>) -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut rng = rng.lock().unwrap();
    let range = Uniform::from(0..100);
    let len_u32 = range.sample(&mut *rng);
    let len_usize = usize::try_from(len_u32).unwrap();
    vec![len_u32; len_usize]
}

async fn query_all_items() -> Vec<u32> {
    let rng = Arc::new(Mutex::new(ThreadRng::default()));
    stream::iter(0..)
        .then(|_| async { get_response(Arc::clone(&rng)).await })
        .take_while(|v| future::ready(v.len() >= 10))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .await
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .collect()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // [46, 46, 46, ..., 78, 78, 78], or whatever random list you get
    println!("{:?}", query_all_items().await);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a `while` loop since the `while` will surface the flag more easily.

```
fn query_all_items () -> Vec<Item> {
    let items = vec![];
    let limit = 10;
    let mut limit_reached = false;
    
    while limit_reached {
        let response = queryItems(limit).await?;

        limit_reached = response.len() >= limit;
    
        items.extend(response);
    }

    items
}
```

Comment: I think you must mean `while !limit_reached`?

Answer (score 0):

Without context it's hard to advise ideal code. I would do:

```rust
fn my_body_is_ready() -> Vec<u32> {
    let mut acc = vec![];
    let min = 10;

    loop {
        let foo = vec![42];

        if foo.len() < min {
            acc.extend(foo);
            break acc;
        } else {
            acc.extend(foo);
        }
    }
}
```